# Piping PID into jstack

Tags: linux, command-line, process, java

I've written a command line that effectively extracts the highest CPU java PID thread process from top -H (example code):

```
top -H -n 1 | grep "java" | head -n 1 | cut -d' ' -f1
```

I want to inspect the PID in jstack. Due to how fast the threads appear and disappear, it's not possible to enter the PID manually, and I was hoping to pipe the result directly into jstack, however whenever one does, for example (simplest code example that reproduces the issue):

```
12345 | jstack
```

jstack merely throws up the usage help page, as if pipe isn't sending the variable to jstack.

How can I get the PID I've got with my command into jstack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`jstack`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstack.html) expects the process id to be provided as a parameter, so you should use command substitution:

```
jstack "$(top -H -n 1 | grep "java" | head -n 1 | cut -d' ' -f1)"
```

You can use `ps` to find the process instead of filtering `top`’s output:

```
jstack "$(ps -C java -o pid --sort %cpu --no-headers | head -n 1)"
```

This uses `ps` to find processes whose command matches `java`, outputs their PID only, sorted by CPU usage, with no headers, and keeps the first one; the result is given to `jstack`.

To find [the thread ID using the most CPU](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15815829/4500798), output `tid` instead, with the `-L` option to get `ps` to process threads:

```
ps -L -C java -o tid --sort %cpu --no-headers | head -n 2
```

(I’m extracting the first two because the first will always match the PID, which groups all the CPU usage for the process as a whole).

You can use `printf` to output that in hexadecimal:

```
printf "%x\n" $(ps -L -C java -o tid --sort %cpu --no-headers | head -n 2)
```

Comment: Using top -H to inspect individual thread processes (as ps lumps all java threads together) as I'm trying to track down individual Java processes that are hogging CPU. Wasn't aware variable substitution was a thing, so thank you for solving my problem!

Comment: I realise you were using `top -H`, however since you’re extracting the PID from `top`, not the TID, I didn’t think there would be any practical difference with the `ps` approach — do you have a scenario where there is?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not knowledgeable enough to comment. I was attempting to follow (somewhat) the steps detailed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15815829/889894